# How can I disable MX Keys Wireless Keyboard backlight

Tags: backlight, logitech, keys

How can I disable Logitech MX Keys Wireless Keyboard backlight on 20.04. I want to turn off LEDs completely with a GUI or command line tool.

I was able to turn off LEDs of my Logitech mouse with Piper app.

Comment: You *might* be able to do this with [Solaar](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar). Be sure to check the [supported devices page](https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/devices) for your keyboard model and the functionality available. Alternatively, there’s [logiops](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops), but this is a bit more complicated to use.

Comment: Thank you @matigo. Before reading your post, I thought of plugging it into windows 10. I plugged the keyboard into windows 10 with Logitech g hub installed. G suite suggested installing the Logitech Options app. It installed. Then without any configuration, I noticed that all the keyboard lights were off.  This continued on Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 4):

Press and hold <kbd>F6</kbd> until backlight is off.

Answer (score 2):

C. Rogers is wrong
Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd> will only control the brightness of your monitor.

You have to press either <kbd>F7</kbd> to turn the backlights off, or <kbd>F7</kbd> to turn the urge backlight back on.

Comment: F7 does nothing on my keyboard, F7 is labelled rewind and probably if I was playing media when I hit it, it should do that but seems to have nothing to do with the backlight.

Answer (score 2):

Hold the function key (<kbd>Fn</kbd>) and hit <kbd>F6</kbd> to turn off the backlighting and <kbd>F7</kbd> to turn it back on.  Not <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd> as previously stated.

Answer (score 0):

The Fn+F6 brings the light down. After a while or power cycling the keyboard the light is back on. It's like it won't save the settings. I tried updating firmware, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

This answer works on LinuxMint 20.3 Cinnamon with a MX Keys Mini model code YR0084

This keyboard has a "reduce brightness" icon on the F4 key and "increase brightness" on the F5 key.    Pressing and holding either key (WITHOUT using CTRL or Fn) works. However it may take a second or two for you to actually notice the brightness change.

NOTE: switching the keyboard off and on again, the backlights will reactivate by default - they will not remember the setting.

Answer (score 0):

I held down the function key and hit F4 (the key with the sunset icon). I held it down and hit the F4 button three times and it finally dimmed and stayed off.

Answer (score 0):

logitech was too stupid to let you control the brightness, because at max it does not last as long lmao. put a piece of tape over the green/red led indicator as that is also where the photo sensor is, THIS STOPS THE AUTO DIMMING
however logitech was also so cheap and or intentional that every single time you reboot you need to max the brightness again
other then that i love this kb

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to install anything. Just hold the <kbd>Fn</kbd> Key and tap <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd> to lower or raise brightness on the keyboard. Was looking for answers, when the icons on the keys were right there staring me in the face. Hehe.

Comment: The keys are F5 and F6

Comment: @boatcoder, you do mean F7 and F7, right?

Comment: Can't remember right now and I've been away from my boat and my keyboard for 2 months :-D. Pretty sure I did not typo that though.